# Do flatpak programs provide auto-updates?

Tags: flatpak

I read what the creators of Elementary OS said about flatpack and PPA.

And I agreed - PPA is not so secure.

But if I install, say Krita, from flatpak, I will have the latest version, BUT will I receive updates? Or will I have to do it manually?

Because installing PPA is maybe less secure but convenient IF flatpak cannot be updated by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! I was prompted and installed a few updates for a few of my flatpak apps. In fact, I updated Visual Studio Code after being prompted this morning.

Comment: do I have control over the updates?  I live in Myanmar and internet is slow and by mb. Many times don't really care about incremental updates for regular apps.

Comment: updates will show up in the AppCenter along with other elementary OS updates and you can choose which ones to install.